# Passing a parameter from Jenkins into Java

Tags: java, jenkins

We've set up some parameters for executing a build in Jenkins (using the simple "parameterized build" setting). The job is set up as Maven test.
Is there a way to programmatically pass those parameters into our Java code? We need to execute certain update functions based on the parameter set via Jenkins.

Comment: are u try use System.getenv() ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can pass your Jenkins parameters to your Java code through the maven execution like this:

`mvn clean test -Dparam1=$JOB_PARAM_1`

Note that the **$JOB_PARAM_1** will capture the value of the parameter set on Jenkins. This is for Unix environments, if you are working with Jenkins on Windows, then use **%JOB_PARAM_1%** instead.

Comment: In that example you will get the value on your Java code using System.getProperty("param1");

Answer (score 0):

To set the properties, you need to set it using the commandline. 
For example :    export BROWSER =chrome

You can set it in This build is parameterized section of your jenkins build configuration.

you have BROWSER parameter set in jenkins configuration then you can use %BROWSER% in your pom where you need to set the browser.