# Selenium- Jenkins send value variable to Junit

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, automation

I would like to pass url parameter from Jenkins.

```
driver.navigate().to("url");
```

Comment: So where are you stuck? Do you see any errors? Update the question with error stack trace.

Comment: no there are no errors, but I would like to understand how to pass the parameter in input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you use Maven:**

In order to accept the build parameter from Jenkins, use the System.getProperty object. For example, to accept a property called "PerfectoUsername" use the following code:

```
String user = System.getProperty("PerfectoUsername");
```

Details: [Passing a parameter from Jenkins into Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39725126/passing-a-parameter-from-jenkins-into-java)